# Python Dictionaries: Running Custom Functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, switch-statement, case

Please assist me with the following.  I've run through a few similar questions of on Stack, but the examples provided do not address the problem that I'm experiencing.

In the dictionary below, I would like to run a custom function when the user types "Option 1".

> With the current setup, the custom function - writeFunction() - is
>   executed regardless of which option the user chooses.

**The output when choosing 'Option 1':**

- This function works
- None

**The output when choosing 'Option 2':**

- This function works
- Answer 2

If I change Option 1 to a string value it executes perfectly.  What the heck am I doing wrong?

```
# Custom Function
def writeFunction():
    print("This function works")

# Case statement
def case(arg):
    switch = {
        'Option 1':writeFunction(),
        'Option 2':'Answer 2',
        'Option 3':'Answer 3'
    }
    sysResponse = switch.get(arg,"Value not in list")
    print(sysResponse)

# User selection
userSelection = input("Please select option 1 to 3: ")

# Run case statement based on user selection
case(userSelection)
```

I want to avoid using endless elif statements.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a reference to the function (notice the lack of `()` after `writeFunction`) in the dict, then check whether the object you retrieve to `sysResponse` is callable; if it is, call it to replace the actual value.

This has the added bonus that if `writeFunction` has side-effects or is slow to execute, it'll only be executed if it's chosen.

```
switch = {
    'Option 1': writeFunction,
    'Option 2': 'Answer 2',
    'Option 3': 'Answer 3'
}
sysResponse = switch.get(arg, "Value not in list")
if callable(sysResponse):
    sysResponse = sysResponse()
```

Comment: For consistency, maybe use `lambda: 'Answer X'` for the other options? (Also should change function to return the string, otherwise it will asign `None` to `sysResponse`)

Comment: This works brilliantly!!! Thank you so much.
Just added else: print(sysResponse) in order to return the string values under Option 2 and 3.